# Type 'Any' has no subscript members error Json

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsdictionary, any

I got this Error

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

on the lines with 'dayZeroTemperatureMax, dayZeroTemperatureMin' ect and I don't know how to fix it. I searched on the internet but all their fixes won't fix my problem. This is what i got:

```
struct Weekly {

    var dayZeroTemperatureMax: Int
    var dayZeroTemperatureMin: Int

    var dayOneTemperatureMax: Int
    var dayOneTemperatureMin: Int
    var dayOneTime: String?
    var dayOneIcon: UIImage

    init (weatherDictionary: NSDictionary) {

        let weeklyWeather = weatherDictionary["daily"] as! NSDictionary

        let weeklyForcast = weeklyWeather["data"] as! NSArray

        //DAY ZERO
        dayZeroTemperatureMax = weeklyForcast[0]["temperatureMax"] as! Int
        dayZeroTemperatureMin = weeklyForcast[0]["temperatureMin"] as! Int

        //DAY ONE
        dayOneTemperatureMax = weeklyForcast[1]["temperatureMax"] as! Int
        dayOneTemperatureMin = weeklyForcast[1]["temperatureMin"] as! Int
        let dayOneTimeIntValue = weeklyForcast[1]["sunriseTime"] as! Int
        dayOneTime = weeekDateStringFromUnixtime(dayOneTimeIntValue)
        let dayOneIconString = weeklyForcast[1]["icon"] as! String
        dayOneIcon = weatherIconFromString(dayOneIconString)

      }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` / `NSDictionary` in Swift. Both don't provide type information. This causes the error

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not know what type `weeklyForcast[0]` is, so you should do the following:

```
if let zeroWeeklyForecast = weeklyForcast[0] as? [String: Int] {
    dayOneTemperatureMax = zeroWeeklyForecast["temperatureMax"]
    dayOneTemperatureMin = zeroWeeklyForecast["temperatureMin"]
}
```

If `weeklyForcast[0]` is a `[String: Any]` and not `[String: Int]` you would have to cast from `Any` to `Int` as well.

As mentioned in the comments, `NSDictionary` should no longer be used in Swift and should be replaced by `[Type1: Type2]`. More importantly, if you are decoding data from JSON, you should consider using `JSONDecoder`. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4) is a good tutorial.

Comment: The better solution is to avoid using `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` in Swift.

Comment: Agree 100% with you. Let update answer.